# sortable lists overlapping and preventing drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have here a JSfiddle demonstrating my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/J6uM5/4/

```
<div id="list-A" style="height:50px; overflow-y:scroll; border:1px solid red">
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
    <li>item 13</li>
    <li>item 14</li>
    <li>item 15</li>
    <li>item 16</li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="list-B">
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the JS

```
$(function() {
$('.sortable').sortable({

    connectWith: ".sortable",
    scroll:false,

}).disableSelection();
```

});

The issue is that sortable1 (although hidden by the div) still extends to sortable2 in the dom. In order to successfully drag an item from list1 to list2, you must be scrolled to the bottom of list1 or if you are scrolled down far enough that list1 isnt overlapping list2. Any work around would be appreciated.

Comment: I have been messing with this for some time now, it seems that this problem is most obvious in Firefox, chrome handles this situation much better, to the point where one cannot even tell there is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the height/overflow on the actual sortable list (ul) instead of the wrapper, it seems to work.

```
#sortable1 {
    height:25px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding-bottom:35px;
}
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/J6uM5/8/

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: In my original code, I did actually have the styles applied directly to the list. I am still experiencing the same problem. Strangely the code you have submitted seems to work, I am confused why it is not working for me.